# How to change ownership using chown, so that I can update serverless globally?

Tags: node.js, serverless, chown, aws-serverless

I think this is a very basic issue I am getting, but I am unsure how to proceed from here due to my lack of knowledge using `chown`.

I am trying to run `sudo npm install serverless -g` but am getting the following feedback on my CLI:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                serverless update check failed                 │
│              Try running with sudo or get access              │
│             to the local update config store via              │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/myUsername/.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I am not entirely sure what exactly the command
`sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/myUsername/.config`
means.

I'd like to be sure that I am not going to break some configurations for `npm`.

Could someone point out what exactly I am looking at and help me understand the syntax?

Some clarifications would be amazing around:
-R
-id -gn

Trying to change the $USER with myUsername in different combinations results in no success either, as I am getting the same problem again.

Some pointers would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Grossly speaking, the chown command goes like this `chown [flags] username:usergroup files`.

For your question, I think there are two parts that needs to be explained:

1. The `R` flag. This flag is to apply the changes recursively, it means it will change the ownership of the folder and for the subfolders also.
2. The `-id -gn` after the user name. For this I was not so sure, but I ran across this answer (link in the end) and apparently it will return the group of the current user.

In the chown command, you must pass the `username:usergroup`, so if you use `-id -gn` it will pass the user group of the username you passed. It is most useful when you don't know your usergroup.

Hope I was helpful.

Israel

Link for the other question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/916840/chown-usernameusername-xauthority